# Get output in given format in python

Tags: python

I currently self learning python and want to simulate logic gates in python.

I came across this below code for logic gate simulation

```
class Connector :
   def __init__ (self, owner, name, activates=0, monitor=0) :
      self.value = None
      self.owner = owner
      self.name  = name
      self.monitor  = monitor
      self.connects = []
      self.activates= activates

 def connect (self, inputs) :
   if type(inputs) != type([]) : inputs = [inputs]
   for input in inputs : self.connects.append(input)


def set (self, value) :
   if self.value == value : return      # Ignore if no change
   self.value = value
   if self.activates : self.owner.evaluate()
   if self.monitor :
      print ("Connector {0}-{1}set to {2}" .format(self.owner.name,self.name,self.value))

  for con in self.connects:
      con.set(value)

class LC :
   def __init__ (self, name) :
   self.name = name

   def evaluate (self) : return

class Not (LC) :         # Inverter. Input A. Output B.
   def __init__ (self, name) :
      LC.__init__ (self, name)
      self.A1 = Connector(self,'A1',activates=1)
      self.B1 = Connector(self,'B1')

   def evaluate (self) : self.B1.set(not self.A1.value)

class Gate2 (LC) :  # two input gates. Inputs A, B. Output C.
   def __init__ (self, name) :
      LC.__init__ (self, name)
      self.A = Connector(self,'A',activates=1)
      self.B = Connector(self,'B',activates=1)
      self.C = Connector(self,'C')

class And (Gate2) :       # two input AND Gate
   def __init__ (self, name) :
      Gate2.__init__ (self, name)

   def evaluate (self) : self.C.set(self.A.value and self.B.value)

a = And('N1')
a.C.monitor=1
a.A.set(1)
a.B.set(1)

n = Not('N2')
a.C.connect(n.A1)
n.B1.monitor=1
```

This will provide the output

```
Connector N1-C set to 1
Connector N2-B1 set to 0
```

I understood the logic.
Here the output C of 'AND gate' is connected to wire N1 and output B1 of 'OR gate' is connected to wire N2 and it is printed.

If In this I want to display input of 'NOT Gate' i.e A1 is connected to wire N1 i.e, along with above output

```
Connector N1-A1 set to 1
Connector N1-C set to 1
Connector N2-B1 set to 0
```

N1 is wire connecting output of AND gate I.e C and input of NOT gate I.e A1.
How can I do this.
Anyone please help.

[image]

Comment: When do you want the input displayed? At connect call? At set call? Will you always simulate the code in the order above?

Comment: Want the input to display at set call. Order can change

Comment: Add a line before each set call in loop over connects `for con in self.connects : con.set(value)` in set function in Connector class?

Comment: I didn't get you sir. Can you please explain what logic should I need to add in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to write here, comment section is too small and packed :(

---

Starting from `a.B.set(0)` at the last line.

Since `a.B`'s activation = 1, it's going to call `evaluate` function which calls `a.C.set(0)`(0 because 0 and 1).

Then at last line of `a.C.set(0)` call, it will loop over the connected "Connector"s,

which - in your sample - is [`n.A`].

So before going on to call `con.set(0)`, add a line you want to display.

`print(f"{self.owner.name}-{self.name} is connected to wire {con.owner.name}-{con.name}")`

"self" in the line above is `a.C` and "con" would be `n.A`.

---

`for con in self.connects : con.set(value)`

to

```
for con in self.connects:
    con.set(value)
    print(f"{self.owner.name}-{self.name} is connected to wire {con.owner.name}-{con.name}")
```

Keep in mind that `set` can trigger evaluate function recursively.

Thus, if you print after the `set`, the result may be pushed far back of the line.

---

Result

```
Connector N1-C set to 1
Connector N1-C set to 0
Connector N2-B set to True
N1-C is connected to wire N2-A
```

---

Changed the print content to display connection status.

Changed the format of truth evaluation result to 0/1 from True/False.

```
    def set(self, value):
        if self.value == value: return  # Ignore if no change
        self.value = value
        if self.activates: self.owner.evaluate()
        if self.monitor:
            print("Connector {0}-{1} set to {2}".format(self.owner.name, self.name, 1 if self.value else 0))

        for con in self.connects:
            con.set(value)
            print(f"{con.name} is connected to wire {self.owner.name}")
```

In your sample output,

```
Connector N1-A1 set to 1
Connector N1-C set to 1
Connector N2-B1 set to 0
```

there is no `A1` in `N1` - `AND` class which inherits `Gate2` class. Only 'A' and 'B' are present.

To look as similar as possible to your sample, I made some twist in the simulation code.

```
    a = And('N1')
    n = Not('N2')
    a.C.connect(n.A1)

    a.A.monitor = 1  # now we see the value in N1-A
    a.C.monitor = 1
    n.A1.monitor = 1 # and the value in N2-A1
    n.B1.monitor = 1
    
    a.A.set(1)
    a.B.set(1)
```

Now I have this as a result:

```
Connector N1-A set to 1
Connector N1-C set to 1
Connector N2-B1 set to 0
Connector N2-A1 set to 1
A1 is connected to wire N1
```

`N2-B1` is displayed before `N2-A1` and `connection status line` because of the recursive call to `set` from `evaluate` ; i.e. stack

---

```
    # dict to trace back origins
    origins = {}
    for gate in [a, n]:
        gate_type = gate.__class__.__name__

        if gate_type == "And":  # contains A, B, C connector
            connections = gate.A.connects + gate.B.connects + gate.C.connects
            for connection in connections:
                origins[connection] = gate

        if gate_type == "Not":  # contains A1, B1 connector
            connections = gate.A1.connects + gate.B1.connects
            for connection in connections:
                origins[connection] = gate

    # print each gate
    for gate in [a, n]:
        gate_type = gate.__class__.__name__

        if gate_type == "And":
            out_str = f"a AND (connector {gate.name} - "

            connectors = [gate.A, gate.B, gate.C]
            connectors_str = [con.name if con not in origins.keys() else origins[con].name + " connected to " + con.name for con in connectors]

            print(out_str + ', '.join(connectors_str) + ')')

        if gate_type == "Not":
            out_str = f"n Not (connector {gate.name} - "

            connectors = [gate.A1, gate.B1]
            connectors_str = [con.name if con not in origins.keys() else origins[con].name + " connected to " + con.name for con in connectors]

            print(out_str + ', '.join(connectors_str) + ')')
```

Then I get:

```
a AND (connector N1 - A, B, C)
n Not (connector N2 - N1 connected to A1, B1)
```